# Load the whole database with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, memory, sqlite, eager

I am using SQLite3 and Hibernate with Java. Can I somehow load the whole database in memory or fetch all data from the database so that I can access mapped objects fastest? For example if we have a Company and Employee classes and in Company we've mapped the Employees as company.getEmployees(). I would like to fetch all companies from the database and later when I call this method I'd like to get the employees immediately. So is there a way to preload them? Further, if employee is mapped to other objects, can I preload them too? To summarize, I'd like to load the whole database and use the ORM to access the data. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is simply blazing performance you have several options:

- Configure Hibernate 2nd-level [cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-cache)
- In addition to prior point, configure [query cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-querycache) if your data doens't change much.
- Instead of SQLite use [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) or [H2](http://www.h2database.com) in-memory SQL databases in embedded mode
- Use [ObjectDB](http://www.objectdb.com/) with a large shared [cache](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/cache).  JPA compliant OODB.
- Use MongoDB.  A very fast in-memory NoSQL solution

I suggest ObjectDB if you aren't required to use SQL.

(EDITS: Removed eager fetching, added query cache.)

Comment: I think he'll get a lot better by implementing the first step only. I agree with the rest though, but if its too much effort, configuring a good cache will do a good job.

Answer (score 0):

Set all relationships in your entity classes to eager. If you are using JPA annotations:

```
public class Company{

private List<Employee> employeeList;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public List<Employee> getEmployeeList() {
        return employeeList;
    }
}
```

This will fetch all the employees automatically when you retrieve a company from database. Please note this could affect the performance dramatically.

Comment: Are you sure this won't make request every time I call getEmployeeList?

Comment: Totally, as long as it is the same object. Just curious, why would you do that? Take a look at [memcached](http://memcached.org/), it seems a better approach to have an in-memory database

Comment: Cause my database is small (~3 mb) and I use every bit of data stored in it. Thanks!